# Pass selected form input to backend

Tags: php, html, forms

Consider a simple HTML form like

```
<form>

<div>
    <input type='checkbox' name='selections[]' value='1' />
    <input type='text' name="inputs[]" value='' />    
</div>

<div>
    <input type='checkbox' name='selections[]' value='2' />
    <input type='text' name="inputs[]" value='' />    
</div>

<div>
    <input type='checkbox' name='selections[]' value='3' />
    <input type='text' name="inputs[]" value='' />    
</div>

</form>
```

There are three rows, **assume only the 2nd, 3rd rows are checked**, and all three text inputs are filled with (a, b, c), so in my backend (PHP), I can have two arrays

e.g.

```
$selections = array(2, 3);
$inputs = array('a', 'b', 'c');
```

What is the easy way to remove `a` from the $inputs since the checkbox is not checked? i.e. So I can loop the two arrays more easily.

Answer (score 0):

This answer requires detailed knowledge of what's coming in.  Which is rather bad if you want to reuse it.

The following assumptions are being made about the html page:

- The row values start from 1
- The row values are ascending
- The row values are continuous.  e.g. 1, 2, 3...  not 1, 2, 4...

And here's the code:

```
$len = count($selections);

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++)
{
    if (!in_array($i + 1, $selections))
        unset($inputs[$i]);
}
```

Comment: This is a PHP answer?

Comment: Call it a typo.  Fixed now.  Javascript and Java tend to make me forget that php variables are prefixed with a $ symbol.

Comment: PHP doesn't have that syntax for variable types, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting. The `len` isn't necessary could just put `count($selections)` in the `for`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use array_map

```
$inputs = array_map(function($v) use ($inputs) {
    return $inputs[$v - 1];
}, $selections);
```

Though MingShun's answer will work fine if converted to PHP

Answer (score 0):

**You should change your HTML like this**:

```
<form method="post">
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' name='data[0][selections]' value='1' />
    <input type='text' name="data[0][inputs]" value='' />    
</div>

<div>
    <input type='checkbox' name='data[1][selections]' value='2' />
    <input type='text' name="data[1][inputs]" value='' />    
</div>

<div>
    <input type='checkbox' name='data[2][selections]' value='3' />
    <input type='text' name="data[2][inputs]" value='' />    
</div>

<input type="submit"/>
```

**TEST DATA**:

```
<?php 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST['data']);
?>
```

**RESULT**:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [selections] => 1
            [inputs] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [selections] => 2
            [inputs] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [selections] => 3
            [inputs] => 3
        )

)
```

OR:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [inputs] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [selections] => 2
            [inputs] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [selections] => 3
            [inputs] => 3
        )

)
```

**Now you can loop result and handle**.

```
$selections = array();
$inputs = array();

foreach ($_POST['data'] as $item){
    if (!empty($item['selections']) && !empty($item['inputs'])){
        $selections[] = $item['selections'];
        $inputs[] = $item['inputs'];
    }
}

var_dump($selections);
var_dump($inputs);
```